# Emails and Map Reduce Job

Tags: python, dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm just starting out with Hadoop and writing some Map Reduce jobs.  I was looking for help on writing a MR job in python that allows me to take some emails and put them into HDFS so I can search on the text or attachments of the email?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For handling the emails, the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module from the stdlib is probably going to be handy. For the Hadoop side of things, [Using Python with Hadoop](http://werxltd.com/wp/2009/09/29/using-python-with-hadoop/) might be handy, although there are plenty of Google results to choose from.

Comment: @StevenSmith If you go with the dumbo framework mentioned in my prior link, you could look at this short tutorial: https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki/Short-tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you need to use hadoop streaming if you want to use write Python code for running MapReduce Jobs